# Rescheduling a One-Shot job using Quartz

Tags: triggers, scheduling, jobs, quartz.net

I want to use quartz scheduling not based on time interval but to reschedule the job after the job has been completed. The job may complete in 1 min, 2 min etc, but need to be rescheduled to run at 1 (or x) min later.

I already tried using Reschedule in this way but job didnt get fired.

**Scheduling for the first time:**

```
Trigger alertJobTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("alertJobTrigger", 
                                            "triggerGroup1", 
                                            DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60), 
                                            null, 
                                            0, 
                                            TimeSpan.Zero);
 scheduler.ScheduleJob(alertJobDetail, alertJobTrigger);
```

**Trying to reschedule the same job after job completion:**

```
Trigger trigger = Global.scheduler.GetTrigger("alertJobTrigger",
                                              "triggerGroup1");

Trigger newTrigger = new SimpleTrigger("alertJobTrigger",
                                        "triggerGroup1",
                                        trigger.JobName,
                                        trigger.JobGroup,
                                        DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60), 
                                        null, 
                                        0,
                                        TimeSpan.Zero);     

Global.scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.JobName, trigger.JobGroup, newTrigger);
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the trigger name and trigger group of Reschedule. it should be Reschedule("alertJobTrigger", "triggerGroup1",...);

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reschedule job with repeat interval equal to the execution time of the job then you will have to instruct trigger to do that.

Otherwise if you need just repeating job which is executed after the same period of time (recurring) then you can specify `repeatCount = -1` and `repeatInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(..)`. And to prevent multiple execution of the same job if the job fired takes longer that repeatInterval you can use `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute on top of your job to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not create a new Trigger.** Use the same trigger while rescheduling.
This should work:

```
Trigger trigger = Global.scheduler.GetTrigger("alertJobTrigger","triggerGroup1");

trigger.set(); //set whichever values you want.

Global.scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.JobName, trigger.JobGroup, trigger);
```

Comment: may i know which version of quartz.net you considered for the above answer.